# Nonconventional api requests with backbonejs (such as get by email)

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-model

I am building a backbonejs client, but to populate the models, I do not know the id to request from the server. Instead, I only have the email address attribute.

The API has an endpoint like `v1/people/:email_address`, and I'd like to use that to populate my model.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Assuming the email address is unique, you can simply define that as the unique identifying attribute of the model

```
var People = Backbone.Model.extend({
  idAttribute: "email_address"
});
```

You can also define a `url` method that computes the URL for a model.

```
var People = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: function() {
    return 'v1/people/:' + this.get('email_address')
  }
});
```

If you're fetching data using a collection instead of individual models, you can do the same thing on the collection.

Comment: What if sometimes I want to get by email address, which is unique, but also other times I want to be able to fetch  by unique id (in the rare case where I actually have the ID)

Comment: You'll have to override the `Backbone.sync` method for your model